# Updating a list of chat messages in a large set of messages

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've seen many similar questions about this topic, but nothing quite hit home for me, and I'd like to solidify my understanding of keys in React.

Suppose a `ChatList` component grabs a list of chat messages from state and renders them (I'm using Effector here, but this would apply to something like Redux as well):

```
const ChatMessage = React.memo(({ text }) => {
    return <div>
        {text}
    </div>
})

const getKey = ({ id, read, delivered, pending }) => `${id}_${read}_${delivered}_${pending}`;

const ChatList = React.memo(() => {
    const chatMessages = useUnit($chatMessages);

    const mappedMessages = React.useMemo(() => {
        return chatMessages.map((chatMessage) => {
            <ChatMessage key={getKey(chatMessage)} message={chatMessage} />
        })
    }, [chatMessages]);

    return <div>
        {mappedMessages}
    </div>
})
```

Here, a chat message looks something like this:

```
interface IChatMessage {
    id: string; // suppose I generate a uuid for each message
    read: boolean;
    delivered: boolean;
    pending: boolean;
}
```

I'm also using `FlatList` from react-native, however the same concepts would apply, I'd imagine. Each `ChatMessage` component has its own unique key, and in order to ensure that the component gets rerendered to reflect its current status (read, delivered, edited, etc), I don't just use its value for `id` as the key, I use these statuses.

This works as is, however my question is more about performance, really. For the sake of this question, suppose I could have any amount of chat messages in my state. When I hit 'send', I pull the state and then send the chat message over a socket:

```
const sendChatMessage = async ({
    chatMessages,
    chatMessage,
    socket
}: {
    chatMessages: IChatMessage[];
    chatMessage: IChatMessage;
    socket: Socket
}) => {
    console.log(chatMessage); // { id: '<uuid>', delivered: false, read: false, pending: true }
    // update UI first with a "pending" icon
    setChatMessages([...chatMessages, chatMessage]);

    // emit via socket this new chat message
    socket.emit('send_message', { chatMessage });
}
```

Here I am appending this new message, I'd imagine this is the best practice. But then right away, I would receive a reply from my backend:

```
// this event is used to mark the new message as no longer 'pending'
socket.on('reply__send_message', { chatMessageId } => {
    const chatMessages = $chatMessages.getState();
    const chatMessage = chatMessages.find((chatMessage) => chatMessage.id === chatMessageId);

    setChatMessages(chatMessages.map((chatMessage) => {
        if (chatMessage.id === chatMessageId) {
            return {
                ...chatMessage,
                pending: false
            }
        }

        return chatMessage
    }));
})
```

Furthermore, if the target user is currently online, they will receive or 'read' the message (if their currently-opened chat is with the source user who just sent out the new message):

```
socket.on('mark_message_as', { chatMessageId, markAs /* 'read' | 'received' */ } => {
    const chatMessages = $chatMessages.getState();
    const chatMessage = chatMessages.find((chatMessage) => chatMessage.id === chatMessageId);

    setChatMessages(chatMessages.map((chatMessage) => {
        if (chatMessage.id === chatMessageId) {
            return {
                ...chatMessage,
                [markAs === 'read' ? 'read' : 'received']: true,
            }
        }

        return chatMessage
    }));
})
```

Am I using the best practices and correctly updating the state in `chatMessages`? These back and forth communications + UI updates may occur frequently, as showcased above, so I'm just curious if I should be doing something else. I'm making good use of `React.memo` and `key` here, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

for the long and complex list, I often use the flash-list instead of FlatList https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list

Comment: Yeah, but I ran into performance issues with it, so I eventually phased it out and went back to Flatlist. There was too much jank, because my estimated element height was way too variable